# MKL Performance on Intel Phi

Tags: c, openmp, intel-mkl, intel-vtune, intel-mic

I have a routine that performs a few MKL calls on small matrices (50-100 x 1000 elements) to fit a model, which I then call for different models.  In pseudo-code:

```
double doModelFit(int model, ...) {
   ...
   while( !done ) {
     cblas_dgemm(...);
     cblas_dgemm(...);
     ...
     dgesv(...);
     ...
   }
   return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ...
  c_start = 1;  c_stop = nmodel;
  for(int c=c_start; c<c_stop; c++) {
    ...
    result = doModelFit(c, ...);
    ...
  }
}
```

Call the above version 1.  Since the models are independent, I can use OpenMP threads to parallelize the model fitting, as follows (version 2):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ...
  int numthreads=omp_max_num_threads();
  int c;
#pragma omp parallel for private(c)
  for(int t=0; t<numthreads; t++) {  
     // assuming nmodel divisible by numthreads...      
     c_start = t*nmodel/numthreads+1; 
     c_end = (t+1)*nmodel/numthreads;
     for(c=c_start; c<c_stop; c++) {
        ...
        result = doModelFit(c, ...);
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

When I run version 1 on the host machine, it takes ~11 seconds and VTune reports poor parallelization with most of the time spent idle.  Version 2 on the host machine takes ~5 seconds and VTune reports great parallelization (near 100% of the time is spent with 8 CPUs in use).  Now, when I compile the code to run on the Phi card in native mode (with -mmic), versions 1 and 2 both take approximately 30 seconds when run on the command prompt on mic0.  When I use VTune to profile it:

- Version 1 takes the same roughly 30 seconds, and the hotspot analysis shows that most time is spent in __kmp_wait_sleep and __kmp_static_yield.  Out of 7710s CPU time, 5804s are spent in Spin Time.
- Version 2 takes fooooorrrreevvvver... I kill it after running a couple minutes in VTune.  The hotspot analysis shows that of 25254s of CPU time, 21585s are spent in [vmlinux].

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here and why I'm getting such bad performance?  I'm using the default for OMP_NUM_THREADS and set KMP_AFFINITY=compact,granularity=fine (as recommended by Intel).  I'm new to MKL and OpenMP, so I'm certain I'm making rookie mistakes.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: MKL has some serious performance problems with small matrices on Phi. I recommend posting your question on the Intel forums: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-many-integrated-core

Comment: @pburka I've posted over there too.  Just trying to cast a wider net.  :)  Do you have a link for the small matrix problems?

Comment: Here's one problem http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475924 . I'm also following up with Intel through Premier Support. In this case I believe that MKL reduces the number of threads to 30, and then it takes 1ms to spin the threads back up after the GEMM call. But I also believe that this is not the only GEMM performance problem.

Comment: @pburka I just saw your post over at Intel, and your sizes are comparable to mine.  I didn't pad to get divisible by 64 dimensions (which I will try) but that doesn't seem like the right answer.  Are you saying that (hypothetically) it is automatically spawning ~8 threads to compute models, each of which spawns 30 threads for dgemm?  Or am I giving OpenMP too much credit?  Do you know of a way to figure out who spawns what threads on the Phi?

Comment: I don't know a good way. I stepped through MKL using gdb to figure out what it was doing. The OpenMP source is public, so you can instrument that. https://www.openmprtl.org/

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this behavior given that most of the time is spent in OS (vmlinux), is over-subscription caused by nested OpenMP parallel region inside MKL implementation of `cblas_dgemm()` and `dgesv`. E.g. see [this example](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/tutorials/mkl_mmx_c/GUID-8DB79DF7-B853-46C9-8F46-C3782E0CA401.htm).

This version is supported and explained by Jim Dempsey at the [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475924#comment-1781159).

Answer (score 0):

What about using MKL:sequential library? If you link MKL library with sequential option, it doesn't generate OpenMP threads inside of the MKL itself. I guess you may get better results than now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Generally, links or references to a tool or library should not merely include a specific explanation of how the recommended resource is applicable to the problem, but [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605). (@durron597: Technically, this *is* an answer, just not all that amazing of one.)